# Access Dictionary Value inside list in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dictionary inside a list. I want to access dictionary value inside django template. How can I get that?
views.py

```
def payment_status(request):
    l1=[]
    cand = CandidateDetail.objects.all()


    for person in cand:
        for num in range(0,paid['count']):
            if paid['items'][num]['email']==person.email and paid['items'] 
            [num]['status']=='authorized':
                cand_dict = {'first_name':person.first_name, 
                'last_name':person.last_name, 'email':person.email, 
                 'paid':'Yes'}
                l1.append(cand_dict)


    return render(request, 'desk/payment_status.html',{'cand_list':l1})
```

html file

```
<div class="col-md-10">
      <h3>Candidate Payment Status</h3>
      <table class="cand_list">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Payment Status</th>
        </tr>

        {% for candidate in cand_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ candidate.first_name }} {{ candidate.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ candidate.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ candidate.paid }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      </table>
</div>
```

**The error I am getting is -- Could not parse the remainder: '[item]['first_name']' from 'cand_list[item]['first_name']'**

Answer (score 1):

For a start, iterating over a range of the length of something is *never* the right thing to do - either in Python or in a template.

Secondly, in Django template language you always use dot notation, even for dictionary keys.

So, in your view:

```
for person in cand:
    for item in paid['items']:
        if item['email']== person.email and item['status']=='authorized':
             ....
```

and in your template:

```
    {% for item in cand_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.paid }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{ mydict.key }}

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables)

```
 {% for candidate in cand_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ candidate.first_name }} {{ candidate.last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ candidate.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ candidate.paid }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cand_len list, simply loop over cand_list (list of dict) and access with dict key.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
      <h3>Candidate Payment Status</h3>
      <table class="cand_list">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Payment Status</th>
        </tr>

        {% for item in cand_list %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</td>
          ..
          ..
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Verma PK